# Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module ... not supported

Tags: node.js, typescript, discord.js

I'm making a discord bot in `TypeScript` using `discord.js`. When I tried to compile code this morning I got this error:

```
C:\SECRET\Kostegator\dist\Util\getMeme.js:17
const node_fetch_1 = __importDefault(require("node-fetch"));
                                     ^

Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module C:\SECRET\Kostegator\node_modules\node-fetch\src\index.js from C:\SECRET\Kostegator\dist\Util\getMeme.js not supported.
Instead change the require of index.js in C:\SECRET\Kostegator\dist\Util\getMeme.js to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\SECRET\Kostegator\dist\Util\getMeme.js:17:38)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\SECRET\Kostegator\dist\Util\index.js:15:14)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\SECRET\Kostegator\dist\Commands\BotOwner\startAutoUpdate.js:4:16)
    at C:\SECRET\Kostegator\dist\Client\index.js:61:41
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at ExtendedClient.<anonymous> (C:\SECRET\Kostegator\dist\Client\index.js:58:48)        
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at C:\SECRET\Kostegator\dist\Client\index.js:27:71
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at __awaiter (C:\SECRET\Kostegator\dist\Client\index.js:23:12)
    at ExtendedClient.init (C:\SECRET\Kostegator\dist\Client\index.js:51:16)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\SECRET\Kostegator\dist\index.js:19:4) {
  code: 'ERR_REQUIRE_ESM'
}
```

Here's the GitHub repo: [Kostegator](https://www.github.com/ProGamer2711/Kostegator)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error: require() of ES modules is not supported when importing node-fetch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69041454/error-require-of-es-modules-is-not-supported-when-importing-node-fetch)

Comment: @ZsoltMeszaros Sorry, missclick. Would you mind trying that again? It did solve it I think.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm not sure what you mean by _"Sorry, missclick. Would you mind trying that again?"_

Comment: @ZsoltMeszaros What you sent answered my question but I accidentally clicked "no" when it asked if it helped.

Comment: Oh, I see, no worries :)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The current version of `node-fetch` is ONLY compatible with an ESM import (using `import`), not from CommonJS modules using `require()`.

You have these choices to fix:

1. Switch your project to an ESM module and load it with `import fetch from 'node-fetch';`.
2. In a very recent version of nodejs, you can dynamically import an ESM module into a CommonJS module using `let fetch = await import('node-fetch')`.
3. Use the v2 version of `node-fetch` that still supports being loaded with `require()` as explained [here](https://github.com/node-fetch/node-fetch#commonjs) in the doc.

Answer (score 17):

With the latest update, `node-fetch` only works by using `import`

You could just install the older version of it by
`npm i node-fetch@2.6.1`

Answer (score 7):

For those coming here trying to deploy a NodeJS App using the cPanel feature, remember that under the hood it uses **Phusion Passenger**. This tool needs to have a non-module entry point like:

```
// entry.cjs DONT FORGET TO USE .cjs and not .js

async function loadApp() {
    const { app } = await import("./app.js"); // this is your normal entry file - (index.js, main.js, app.mjs etc.)
}
loadApp()
```

The original answer is here (it deserves your vote): https://stackoverflow.com/a/71901828/14515077

Comment: I spent hours looking for solution, only yours works! Thanks a lot! Is it a problem of the old version of phusion or is it still there?

Comment: I havent tried to deploy something with cPanel in ages but I think that Pushion would someday accept module file as entry points

Answer (score 0):

It will work if you use an older version of the node-fetch module and then use the npm install command. I solved it this way

Comment: You know this has been solved before, right?

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
export const importDynamic = new Function('modulePath', 'return import(modulePath)')
async  function(){
  // replace with your functions
  const {generate} = await importDynamic('random-words')
}
```