# How to use 'require' for node-fetch in a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, commonjs

I am trying to follow [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g8COh40v2jU&t=3857s).

I am stuck at 1:04.

Ania is able to start the netlify dev and return results from her database.

I get an error with the function. I can see in Ania's github repo, that she uses the code that generates the error for me. I wish I could begin to understand why she doesn't get the same error from the same code.

The function Ania wrote uses a require statement as follows:

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
```

When I use this line, I get an error that says:

> Error - require() of ES Module
> /Users/melaniemaslem/AniaKubowTutorials/netflix-datastax-clone/node_modules/node-fetch/src/index.js
> from
> /Users/AniaKubowTutorials/netflix-datastax-clone/functions/getGenres.js
> not supported. Instead change the require of index.js in
> /Users/AniaKubowTutorials/netflix-datastax-clone/functions/getGenres.js
> to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.

I tried replacing the require statement with

```
const fetch = import('node-fetch');
```

When I try that, I get an error that says:

> TypeError - fetch is not a function

I have seen [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70820079/error-err-require-esm-require-of-es-module-not-supported), which suggests I could replace that line with:

```
import fetch from 'node-fetch';
```

When I try that, I get an error that says:

> SyntaxError - Cannot use import statement outside a module

That same SO post has an answer with a fall back suggestion of using something out of date. It links to [this page](https://github.com/node-fetch/node-fetch#commonjs) for advice. I don't know what to make of this or how to apply it to Ania's tutorial.

Can anyone see a way to use require in a function?

Comment: You can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch/v/2.6.7 instead. You can see in her [package.json](https://github.com/kubowania/netflix-clone-graphql-datastax/blob/main/package.json) that Ania is using v 2.6.1

Comment: In other words, run `npm uninstall node-fetch` then `npm install node-fetch@2.6.7`