# Can the npm Webtorrent (v2.1.27) package still run inside node (using typescript)?

Tags: node.js, typescript, commonjs, esmodules, webtorrent

I want to use the webtorrent package inside an Express application in typescript, but no matter how I configure my tsconfig file I keep getting compilation errors

```bash
Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module C...\node_modules\webtorrent\index.js from ...src\controllers\TorrentParser.ts not supported.
index.js is treated as an ES module file as it is a .js file whose nearest parent package.json contains "type": "module" which declares all .js files in that package scope as ES modules.
Instead rename index.js to end in .cjs, change the requiring code to use dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules, or change "type": "module" to "type": "commonjs" in ...\node_modules\webtorrent\package.json to treat all .js files as CommonJS (using .mjs for all ES modules instead).
```

my current `tsconfig.json` looks as follows:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "target": "es2022",
    "allowJs": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "moduleDetection": "force",

    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "noUncheckedIndexedAccess": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,

    "moduleResolution": "NodeNext",
    "module": "NodeNext",

    "outDir": "./dist",
    "rootDir": "./src",
    "types": ["node", "express", "webtorrent"],
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*.ts"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"],
  "ts-node": {
    "files": true
  }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error \[ERR\_REQUIRE\_ESM\]: require() of ES Module ... not supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70820079/error-err-require-esm-require-of-es-module-not-supported)

Comment: `tsconfig.json` is irrelevant here. In `TorrentParser.ts` you're trying to do `require("webtorrent")` and that's not going to work because it's an [ES Module](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#enabling). One option is [using `await import()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70820446).

Comment: my compiler says that top-level awaits are not allowed for CommonJS modules, so I tried using import("webtorrent").then(...). but how do I export members now?
Do I need to wrap the import in an async function and then export whatever it returns? @RickN

Comment: It's very hard to say anything concrete since you didn't share any code. `exports.foo = import('webtorrent').then(module => module.foo);` & `const foo = await require('./TorrentParser.ts').foo;` would work. You should update your question with relevant code & what you've tried so people can help you better.